# Does the POSIX initstate() function take into account the data in the passed state array?

Tags: c, random

```
char *initstate(unsigned int seed, char *state, size_t n);
```

Before calling `initstate()`, should I fill the `state[]` array with some data? Does the `initstate` function ignore the whole content of the state array? Do only the provided `size` and `seed` matter? Is the purpose of `initstate` to fill the `state[]` array without taking into account its current content?

I have seen at least 1 example on the net, filling the state[] array before initstate call. -- I cannot find the url, sorry. -- But, my experience shows that as long as the seed remains the same, the (previous) content of the `state[]` array does not matter. In terms of successive random numbers yielded by the `random()` function.

Comment: Note that `srandom`, `random` and `initstate` are not standard C functions. Why do you need to use these functions instead of the standard C `srand` and `rand` functions? And if you're okay with using non-standard functions there are usually better alternatives than `random` etc., like [`drand48`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/drand48.3.html) (and family).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`initstate()`](https://manned.org/initstate.3) function *"allows a state array `state` to be initialized for use by `random()`"*. In other words, `initstate()` will write a new state into the passed `state` buffer and then set it as the current internal state which will be used (and updated) by subsequent `random()` calls. This can also be seen [in the glibc source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.35.9000/source/stdlib/random_r.c#L230). On the other hand, the `setstate()` function takes an already initialized `state` and sets it as internal state *as is*.

> Is the purpose of `initstate` to fill the `state[]` array without taking into account its current content?

Yep, correct.

> I have seen at least 1 example on the net, filling the `state[]` array before `initstate` call. [...] my experience shows that as long as the seed remains the same, the (previous) content of the `state[]` array does not matter.

You're right, that is unneeded. The data in the array doesn't matter and will be overwritten.